# rusty with simple bash scripts

Tags: bash, substitution, file-rename

I'm working out of very old memory here and I just can't see what's wrong with the following little snippet of a script. I isolated the problem to this part >>

```
#!/bin/sh
for x in   `ls ~/sandbox/inputVids/*.mp4`
do
    echo $x;
    cp "$x" "~/sandbox/outputVids/${x/%.mp4/.silent.mp1}";
done
```

I keep getting the message

> ./makeRepeater.sh: 15: ./makeRepeater.sh: Bad substitution

any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Which is line 15? The code posted looks fine. Perhaps, you are not using bash and using some other shell or have wrong shebang at the top? Do you have `#!/bin/bash` as the first line?

Comment: line in question is the one before last. yes, the file begins with #!/bin/sh

Comment: ubuntu@ip-17:~/sandbox$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Feb 19  2014 /bin/sh -> dash

Comment: You are using `sh`. Use bash i.e. put `#!/bin/bash` as your first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few glitches in your script:

1. No need to parse `ls`'s output
2. Tilde `~` is not expanded inside the double quotes
3. Replacement of string is not using correct pattern
4. Using wrong shebang i.e. `sh` instead of `bash`

Use this script instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/sandbox/inputVids/
for x in *.mp4; do
    echo "$x";
    cp "$x" ~/sandbox/outputVids/"${x/.mp4/.silent.mp1}"
done
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I corrected the script as you said, but I'm still getting the same error on Line 15..

Comment: erorr:: ubuntu@ip-71:~/sandbox$ ./makeRepeater.sh
/home/ubuntu/sandbox/inputVids/VID-20150504-WA0003.mp4
./makeRepeater.sh: 15: ./makeRepeater.sh: Bad substitution

Comment: must be because $x is /home/ubuntu/sandbox/inputVids/VID-20150504-WA0003.mp4 ? I mean instead of just VID-20150504-WA0003.mp4

Comment: ok, that works but I wanted to rename not just the filename, also the path to move it to the outputVids folder .. but this works just as well, thanks. Marking it solved.

Comment: thanks. that was so obvious. I working out of very very old memory here. wow, suddenly i feel old. Yes, it's been 9 years already!

Answer (score 0):

You are `sh` which doesn't understand bash's parameter substitution. Use `bash` i.e. put `#!/bin/bash` as your shebang line.